# Making the ranking query efficient

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using the following code in ACCESS 2010 to rank ~30000 rows from a table. However it takes around 15 minutes to do the ranking (I have to do this for 5 more columns and it could easily take more than an hour). I need these columns for further processing and hence tried creating a new table. I have also tried appending and updating to existing tables. Everything takes the same time. Am I missing something obvious here that could make it work faster?

`SELECT MasterTable.Sales, (SELECT Count(*)+1 as HowMany 
From MasterTable AS Dupe
WHERE Dupe.Sales > MasterTable.Sales) AS SalesRank INTO tableRank
FROM MasterTable;`

Details on the `MasterTable`:
11 columns. 1 primary key (Text). 5 parameters (`Sales` `SalesQty` `Profit` `Hits` `Cost`, all numeric). Ranks of 5 parameters(like `SalesRank` and so on)
30,000 rows

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `Rank`?

Comment: By "Rank", I mean creating a new column with ranks 1 (highest sales) through maximum.

Comment: Can you post the basic details about your `MasterTable`?

Comment: Details on the `MasterTable`:
11 columns. 1 primary key. 5 parameters(like the `Sales`). Ranks of 5 parameters(like `SalesRank`)
30,000 rows

Comment: Sorry, I mean more so like what the column names are, and possibly the data types.

Comment: Details on the `MasterTable`:
11 columns. 1 primary key (Text). 5 parameters (`Sales` `SalesQty` `Profit` `Hits` `Cost`, all numeric). Ranks of 5 parameters(like `SalesRank` and so on, all numeric as well)
30,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a left join with grouping?

```
SELECT
    m1.Sales,
    COUNT(*) AS HowMany
FROM
    MasterTable AS m1
    LEFT JOIN MasterTable m2 ON m1.Sales <= m2.Sales
GROUP BY
    m1.Sales
```

Comment: It taking more time to run than the original code. Thank you anyways.

Comment: regular join would worked too.  Shouldnt take 15 minutes though