# Adding a column to existing table in access without using any relationship

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on a project in ACCESS 2010 that requires me to give a rank to 30000 products based on their sales. I have tried using a query to do the ranking and it takes a long time. (Please find codes at [Making the ranking query efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848800/making-the-ranking-query-efficient))

I figured out that instead, I can just sort the table based on the Sales column and add a field with numbers 1 to 30000.

So is there a way to add such a column, i.e. a column without any relationship to the existing table.

Comment: Where are you getting the sales number? What is the relationship between `sales` and `products`?

Comment: the 'sales' and 'products' are a part of a single table. The table has 11 columns. 
The product name - Primary key
5 Parameters to be ranked (for example sales, hits, profit, etc)
5 columns to hold the different ranks.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding where you're at as far as your progress. Do you have a method for the ranking, and you just want to add a column? Or do you need to know how to get the ranking into the table?

Comment: Pretend you have a query that has been sorted how you want it.  Then adding a column that simply starts row 1 and counts up till the last row.  That is what I believe OP is trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field to the actual table? If that's the case, make a table and run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName
ADD COLUMN yourColumnName AUTOINCREMENT(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked great with some pre-processing and post-processing. But it saves a lot of execution time.